# Access parent directive $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two directives a wrapper with common values and a inner directive, in the controller i have a object `element`

in the template i have

```
<div wrapper="element">
  <div inner="name"></div>
  <div inner="lastname"></div>
</div>
```

Example: I want bind element.name property from inner directive, inner directive its a complex widget

i trying to access to `element` from inner through wrapper, how i can achieve it?

wrapper directive

```
{
  scope: {
    wrapper: '='
  }
}
```

inner directive

```
{
  require: '^wrapper',
  scope: {
    inner: '@'  
  }
}
```

in the inner directive template

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.wrapper[inner]" />
```

Not working!

Note: i dont want set for each inner directive the model, Example

```
<div wrapper="element">
  <div inner="name" model="element.name"></div>
  <div inner="lastname" model="element.lastname"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You get 'wrapper's directive with $parent, right. So what doesn't work exactly? Why do you want to access `inner` through wrapper if `inner` is already the current scope?

Comment: currently i have to pass many properties to inner and all inners have the same properties i want wraps and use a common directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$parent` may not work correctly in case there are any intermediate scope created by `ng-repeat`, `ng-include`,...

The correct way is to use `require`:

In your parent, define a controller:

```
{
  scope: {
    wrapper: '='
  },
  controller: function ($scope) {
     this.scope = $scope;
  }
}
```

In your inner directive:

```
{
  require: "^wrapper",
  scope: {
    inner: '@'  
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs, wrapperController){
     scope.wrapperScope = wrapperController.scope;
  }
}
```

in the inner directive template

```
<input type="text" ng-model="wrapperScope.wrapper[inner]" />
```

Comment: `controller: function($scope) { this.scope = $scope }` did the trick